# Time needed to refresh questions list from a cache

Tags: discussion, questions, caching

How much time must pass, before my [newly asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27402950/1469208) will appear on my [questions list](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1469208/trejder?tab=questions)?

Currently (as of moment of writing this), <s>thirteen</s> 34 minutes has passed and there is no such update.

This question is just to feed my curiosity. I'm sort of tech-geek, who wish to know *all* about SE! :]

**EDIT**: The funny (?) thing is, that question is searchable (at least it popus up in the "similar" list, when I'm trying to ask a similar question -- for test purposes only, of course), but still isn't visible in my profile -- though over half an hour has now passed since asking it.

Comment: Well, at least thirteen (as in 13) seems way too much. Shouldn't take more than 3-4 minutes (or at least didn't ever take more for me).

Comment: Now, nineteen! :>

Comment: Oh wait, I missed that you're talking about your own questions list. In this case I have absolutely no idea either and it might very well take longer. I thought you were after the general questions list on the front page. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Relax, no problem! :> One upvote and we'll be fine! :>

Comment: Maybe it's waiting to work its way through the new triage queue.

Comment: Beep. Upvote-begger detected ;)

Comment: It appears just fine for me... Afaik the question list on your profile is not cached *at all*. It should appear immediately once you've posted it. Are you sure you're sorted by "newest" or "activity" and not by something like "votes" or "views"?